# Xamarin android : SetImageResource crashes application

Tags: android, xamarin

I have an activity that contains an ImageView.
The image is set in the OnCreate method, it works fine.
But when I start a new activity (same type), on some of my friends phone, the application crashes (not in the emulator, or in my phone.).

I think the error is an outOfMemoryError.

But my images are png of about 100ko, how can that be possible ?
What can I do to fix the problem without resizing the images ?

I recreated a very simple example :

```
using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;

namespace TestBug
{
    [Activity (Label = "TestBug", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate (bundle);
            SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);

            ImageView image = FindViewById<ImageView> (Resource.Id.img);    

            if (Utils.nb == 0) {
                image.SetImageResource (Resource.Drawable.img1);
            } 
            else if (Utils.nb == 1) {
                image.SetImageResource (Resource.Drawable.img2);
            }
            else if (Utils.nb == 2) {
                image.SetImageResource (Resource.Drawable.img3);
            }

            Button button = FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.myButton);    
            Utils.nb = Utils.nb + 1;

            button.Click += ButtonClick;
        }

        protected override void OnDestroy ()
        {
            base.OnDestroy ();
            FindViewById<ImageView> (Resource.Id.img).SetImageBitmap(null);
        }

        public void ButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var intent = new Intent (this, typeof(MainActivity));
            StartActivity (intent);
            Finish ();
        }
    }
}
```

The main.axml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<Button
    android:id="@+id/myButton"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello" />
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/img" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Utils.cs

```
using System;

namespace TestBug
{
    public static class Utils
    {
        public static int nb = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you connect the phone to the computer you can use [Android Device Monitor (DDMS)](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/ddms.html) to view the error output when the exception happens. That could help us analyzing the error.

Comment: Another thing, I don't know if it's a copy/paste error or not but your main.axml file is missing the closing tag for LinearLayout: `</LinearLayout>`

Comment: Hello arndafa, yes it was a copy past error.

About the error, I happens only with my old phone, which is half-broken, I cannot connect it to the computer... I will look if i can add logs.

But i tried with bigger images (600ko), and i crashes too in my emulator ! With outOfMemoryError ! So I'm pretty sure that's the problem.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error on my device. I recommend connecting your friends phone to your computer with debug enabled on his phone. Then observe what happens in the logcat output in Android Device Monitor. If you need help with the error, please update your question with the error output.